# Pass data from editable HTML table to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So i have a JSP page, that contents **editable** table with checkbox in each row, the question is, how can i pass the data from selected rows to servlet?

Can i pass it as a parameter, or get html code in servlet to parse it and get selected data?

Thank you.

Comment: Either Ajax or an HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs some more specifics. But here is a perfect example of how to implement editable tables:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

It is very easy to implement and basic knowledge of jQuery will help you play around as much as you like. It even shows examples of how to use data at Java servlets.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when you want pass the values to the servlet. If you want to make all the selections and then submit, a html form submit will be the best option. once you submit the form, the data will be available in request.getParameterValues('names'). If you want to send values immediately after user selects, then you can use ajax through an onchange event